# Transmission can't access mount: Read-only file system

Tags: permissions, btrfs, transmission

I have a BTRFS external drive mounted at `/mnt/media`. I can create files/directories just fine with the shell (with both my personal user and `transmission` user).

When I try to download something to the mount, Transmission throws `Error: Read-only file system (/mnt/media/sometorrent)`.

```
$ su transmission
$ ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx 1 root media    0 Jan 11 08:47 media

$ echo 'test' > /mnt/media/file
$ cat /mnt/media/file
test
```

`badblocks` and `btrfs check` didn't show any errors with the drive. I could use it with Transmission until recently.

Comment: does `mount` list the device as mounted with the `ro` flag?

Comment: How did you install `transmission`? Flatpak or something?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, it has the `rw` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [NixOS](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-22.11/nixos/modules/services/torrent/transmission.nix) systemd service file, that restricts filesystem access. Just adding `BindPaths=/mnt/media` to `transmission.service` solved the issue!